# How do you keep the console from closing after the program is done in C?

Tags: c, windows, console-application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Best Practice for Combating the Console Closing Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173208/what-is-the-best-practice-for-combating-the-console-closing-issue)

How do you keep the console from closing after the program is done in C? When I try to search for it I find lots of stuff about C++ and other languages, but nothing for C. Also, even for C++ there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer.

So could someone please let me know what the simplest way (doesn't need to be super elegant) way to keep the console open after a C program is done running?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173208/what-is-the-best-practice-for-combating-the-console-closing-issue

Answer (score 19):

The previous answers are all assuming that you want to invoke the console app and then essentially leave it "running" and waiting for user input to terminate. If this is the correct assumption, then +1 to GMan's answer.  However, if you are asking how to invoke this console app from either a shortcut, Start->Run or some other mechanism and leave the cmd window open, then you will need to invoke it via `cmd.exe` itself with the `/k` option like so:

```
cmd.exe /k "foo.exe"
```

This will start a cmd window, run your console app, and then leave the cmd window open. This will address @Thanatos above. He's correct in that you should let the console app close.  Again, for me it's unclear what you're really asking for what the end goal should be.

If I made the wrong assumption(s), feel free to -1 me.

Answer (score 18):

- run the program from the command
  line, instead of executing it
  directly.
- Ctrl+F5 in Visual C++.

Comment: Also, can be done by running a `cmd` prompt (Start | Run | "cmd") and then running the program from there.

Comment: @walyk thats what the first point is about.

Comment: I know, but some GUI-centric folks don't know *how* to get that.

Comment: @wally, honestly, I think anyone who is writing a program probably knows how to open a command line.

Answer (score 10):

Console applications are meant to be run from the console. If you do that, after running you'll be left with your console window, and can easily view the output of your program.

You can use something like `getchar()` to force the application to wait for a key-press.

Comment: It still closed with a getchar() at the end of the file. What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

Let the console close.

If you prohibit, in the program, the console from closing, it will make automation with your program difficult, or it will make the format of the program's input strange.

Instead, fix whatever's running the program in the first place, to not close the terminal window in the first place. If this is MS Visual Studio, try F5 (Start without debugging). If you need debugging, place a breakmark at the program's end. Otherwise, open a command prompt/terminal and run the program there yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your IDE opens the console before the program begins.
2) your program ends
3) the IDE closes the console

a) Just tell the IDE to not close the console ... or
b) make your program not end.

a) No idea how to do it.
b) right before the `return 0;` used to terminate the program add

```
printf("Press ENTER a few times to terminate the program");
fflush(stdout);
getchar(); getchar(); getchar(); getchar();
getchar(); getchar(); getchar(); getchar();
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use getch() at the end of your program.
Another way is to debug the program and place a break point before the end of the program.