# This programming is compiling but not running. Where's the error?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
   int a[3];
   a[0]=1;
   a[1]=2;
   a[2]=3;
   printf("%d", a[2]);
}
```

It isn't showing any errors or warnings. But it isn't running

Comment: Works just fine on my machine. You should consider adding `\` to the `printf` statement to force the buffer to flush, though.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Yes it does run, but so quick you can't even see it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864029/how-do-you-keep-the-console-from-closing-after-the-program-is-done-in-c)

Comment: How do you know it's is not running ? How do you run the program. Which is your operating system?

Comment: What do you mean by formatting it?

Comment: @ChayanKathuria look at the edited question: now it is formatted correctly.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature for `main`.

Comment: Works fine with me too

Answer (score 1):

```
 void main(){
```

is non-standard. `main()` function should return an `int`. Some IDEs/platforms check the return the value of the process. So this might be a problem.
Change it to:

```
 int main(void){
```

If you are using C89 then you should also have a return statement from `main()`. This is not required since C99. In C99 and later, `main()` will implicitly return success if the control reaches the end of main as if you had: `return 0;` at the end of `main()` function.

In C89/C90, you must have a `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` at the end of `main()`. Otherwise, it leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). But this is not required in C99 and C11. There's obviously no other problem in your code except this. So if you still have issues, you need to provide more details about your environment/compiler.

Comment: You forgot to mention the `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: This is not required for `main`! http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3p1

Comment: @MichaelWalz Since C99, it's not required to have explicit `return` from C99. Nonetheless, worth adding.

Comment: Thanks I ignored that.

Comment: Tried adding int to main and return 0. But it still won't run

Comment: @ChayanKathuria "won't run" isn't giving any useful information about the failure. What *exactly* happens? It doesn't give output/crashes? There's no problem with your code. So it's your environment/compiler or malware not allowing you to run executables, etc be a problem.

Comment: @I3x as soon as I press Ctrl+f9, it flashes something for a micro second and that's it. It doesn't take me to the output window.

Comment: @ChayanKathuria Probably it outputs and exits the windows, add `system("pause");` at the end of main() before "return 0;`.