# Keeping console window open after error in haskell executable

Tags: windows, haskell, cmd

How do stop the console window from closing after there has been a error when running a .exe?

I am keeping the window open with `_ <- getLine` but this of course only works if the program runs up to that point.

Comment: This seems to be mainly a question about Windows and its... well, if you want to call that a terminal... ...anyway, it would be a good idea to add what particular version and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to keep the console window opened when invoked from a short cut, try invoking the program with `cmd.exe /k ...`

See, for instance: [How do you keep the console from closing after the program is done in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1864120/866915)