# Console pause in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, console

In C# you can cause the console to wait for a character to be input (which is useful for being able to see the last outputs of a console before the program exits). As a beginner in C++, i'm not sure what the equivalent is. Is there one?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173208/what-is-the-best-practice-for-combating-the-console-closing-issue

Comment: If this is Windows, then it's a duplicate of the one @Christian linked to. Voted to close.

Answer (score 35):

The simplest way is simply:

```
std::cin.get();
```

You can print something like "Press any key to continue..." before that. Some people will tell you about

```
system("pause");
```

But don't use it. It's not portable.

Comment: Note that while `cin.get()` is supposed to read a single character it's probable that your terminal does line buffering so that you will have to press enter before the call to `get()` returns.

Comment: Behavior of  those two samples doesn't behave the same, cin.get() waits for ENTER, and system("pause") returns immediately once user presses ANY key.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
// ...
getchar();
```

The function waits for a single keypress and returns its (integer) value.

For example, I have a function that does the same as `System("pause")`, but without requiring that "pause.exe" (which is a potential security whole, btw):

```
void pause()
{
  std::cout << std::endl << "Press any key to continue...";
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: There is no `pause.exe`; `pause` itself is a built-in command in the Windows shell.

Comment: Well, I was under the impression that the command pause resulted in running a whole process which is basically the program "pause". For example, `system("notepad")` (on windows) starts notepad, so this command definitely *can* launch other executables.

Comment: Not the same: getchar(); waits for ENTER key to be pressed before returning

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the standard, and nothing cross-platform. The usual method is to wait for <Enter> to be pressed, then discard the result.

Comment: The C++ standard library is incorporated in the ANSI/C++ ISO Language standard and contains `std::cin` of class `istream`. This is cross-platform and not "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

The incorrect solution would be to use `system("pause")` as this creates security holes (malicious pause.exe in directory!) and is not cross-platform (pause only exists on Windows/DOS).

There is a simpler solution:

```
void myPause() {
    printf("Press any key to continue . . .");
    getchar();
}
```

This uses `getchar()`, which is POSIX compliant (see [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getchar.html)).
You can use this function like this:

```
int main() {
    ...
    myPause();
}
```

This effectively prevents the console from flashing and then exiting.