# Dev C++ closes immediately after compiling

Tags: c, dev-c++

The title pretty much clarifies the problem. When I write a code in C in Dev C++ that has to do with files, the program compiles very well, but it can't be executed because the 'Run' window closes immediately after compiling. This doesn't happen when I write a code to solve other problems (which aren't about reading files, writing in a file, etc.).

I have tried executing codes that have worked in the past, but for some reason don't execute now. Even though the code might be correct, there is no execution of the code at all.

This thing is really making me so frustrated right now. Could you please help me?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the IDE. Try updating the version.

Comment: Are you saying that when you run your program console window closes immediately?

Comment: Exactly dodo951

Comment: Then you should check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173208/what-is-the-best-practice-for-combating-the-console-closing-issue)

Comment: *Run* or *Compile*? *IDE* window or the *Console* window?

Comment: The program compiles perfectly, but the console window closes immediately